# How to return all fields with FULLTEXT search?

Tags: mysql

This question is connected with [Fulltext search not working when searching the exact title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800986/fulltext-search-not-working-when-searching-the-exact-title)

I'm trying to learn how to search databases efficiently, and came across FULLTEXT searches which seem to be the best option. My tables are still small at this point as I haven't collected a lot of data yet. I had this sql code that would search the table

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST ('hamlet') LIMIT 30;
```

but since there's only one row, it returned nothing. What would be some workarounds, to allow the query to return the info?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what i do:

```
SELECT title ,
MATCH(title) 
AGAINST ('hamlet' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
AS relevance 

FROM test 
WHERE  MATCH(title) 
AGAINST ('hamlet' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 

HAVING relevance > 0 ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

table used:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `name_2` (`title`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `test`
--

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `title`) VALUES
(2, 'hamlet');
```